# Solr import failure - mysql

Tags: mysql, solr, full-text-search, solr8

I am a beginner in Solr. I am using Solr 8.3.1 hosted in a ubuntu 18.04 server with 6 core CPU and 16GB RAM. I have to connect to a mysql server and import data. The table contains 12 columns and 3 million rows. To any solr user, this is not a huge data set.
But consistently I am facing import failure for this dataset.

This is the response i got while importing.

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0
  },
  "initArgs": [
    "defaults",
    [
      "config",
      "solr-data-config.xml"
    ]
  ],
  "command": "status",
  "status": "idle",
  "importResponse": "",
  "statusMessages": {
    "Total Requests made to DataSource": "1",
    "Total Rows Fetched": "1000",
    "Total Documents Processed": "0",
    "Total Documents Skipped": "0",
    "Full Dump Started": "2020-01-19 08:09:56",
    "Total Documents Failed": "1000",
    "Time taken": "0:0:4.525"
  }
}
```

I can import a smaller data set with same configurations (4 rows and 112 rows).

I couldn't find any error log also for debugging.

Comment: while selecting from MySQL are you limiting it with 1000 or 10000 like this ?

Comment: I tried importing 1000. Attached the response i got while doing so.

Comment: After SSH client login as root, what is response from this MySQL CLI request?  SELECT @@max_allowed_packet; ?  What is your average row size (length) of each line of your import file?